# Finding number of 'p' tags and iterate through them to scrape the underlying text using php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

So i don't have any idea about how I can scrape the underlying text of a paragraph from a website page, Which does not have any 'id' or 'class' using php.
One of the way is to count and iterate through the

tags in a , but the div itself gets closed before any

tags are encountered.
I intend to scrape wikitravel.org info in order to learn scraping.
Here is one of the example of the page source of wikitravel.org

```
   <h2><span class="editsection">[<a href="/wiki/en/index.php?title=Kanniyakumari&    amp;action=edit&amp;section=18" title="Edit section: Sleep">edit</a>][<a href="#Sleep" title="click to add a sleep listing" onclick="addListing(this, '18', 'sleep', 'Kanniyakumari');">add listing</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="Sleep">Sleep</span></h2>

   <p>There are numerous hotels, residencies etc. in and around Kanyakumari and therefore, staying over is not be a problem. But there are agents, touts and brokers in every nook and corner looking for unsuspecting tourists. Eschew buying or booking rooms from them, as many a time you end up paying a lot more than the actual price. Vivekananda Kendra can be a good option for people looking for a decent, yet cheap accommodation, but it's around 3 km from Kanyakumari. Prefer hotels near the beach especially if you want to watch the sunrise right out of your bed! Note that, you should quote this preference when booking the room or else, you'll always be given a room without a window opening out to the sea. Moreover many a times, these rooms are in great demand and you'll find yourself shelling a extra 400 - 500 Rs (~10 US$)for such a room. Hotel Sea View, Hotel Sangam and a couple of other hotels offer such rooms and the rent is about Rs. 1100 (~ 25 US$) for 12 hrs. Note that many rooms are priced for 12 hrs  and not per day especially during the peak season.
</p>

<p>ATM's in Kanyakumari:</p>

 <p>Canara Bank 
 Main Road, Kanyakumari 629702, ,
 </p>
 <p>Indian Bank 
  S No 658 / 1, National High Way Opp St Antony'S Higher Secondary Sckanyakumari 629702
 </p>
<p>State Bank Of Travancore 
P.B.No.1, 1/17 Amman Sannathi Street, Kanyakumari, Tamil Nadu, 629702
</p>
```

can anybody help?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser. It is supposed to work with jQuery-like selectors.

Here is an example for your case:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.wikitravel.com/yourpage');
foreach($html->find('p') as $element){
    echo $element->innertext; // the content in all the p tags
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot benjamin for your help. Just one last qurey. <p>tags doesn't have src unlike <img> tags. then how can php echo $element's src?

Comment: Sorry, I was just cutting and pasting from their docs, to access the text use `innertext`. This will extract the text from the `p` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found JQuery the best way to scrape HTML data. Have the PHP render out a page with JQuery which parses the scraped HTML then posts a JSON dataset back to the PHP.

If you want to stick with the pure PHP route try out a library along the lines of: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do you have any examples from past projects you have worked on?